# Transparent Materiel White in render

Tags: rendering, transparency

I'm a complete beginner in Blender. I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/Jmir2bDpZA4 to start learning the basics.

All went fine until I got to render my scene. The water that is looking fine and transparent in the Viewport both with Cycles and Eevee [image: Viewport Eeevee] but appears to be white in my renders. [image: Rendered Image]

I changed almost every parameter in the render tab to find what's wrong but I have absolutely no idea what to do...

Any suggestions ?
Thanks !

Comment: Looks like there is any other geometry overlapping the water - check the outlier and search for a box ;) You've probably just forgot to disable the box for rendering (camera icon)

Comment: Thanks mate ! It was indeed a old sea geometry overlapping the current one... I looked everywhere in the collections, cleaned them up, tweaked render and material parameters. After all those ineffective efforts I tried a simple and desperate "Alt+H" and a bloody hidden white cube showed up ! Practice makes perfect. Now I know that in Blender, what you see is not always what you get...

Thanks again !